# Split string with special characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split

I need to split a string using special characters like " < > = and white space.

Example of the string:

```
  <fileset dir="/tmp/test/my_test" includes="all"/>
```

By now I tried using different combinations but no results
Example:

```
line.split(/<=>"\s+/).each do |line_parsed|
    puts line_parsed
end
```

Comment: expected output ? please show us

Comment: line_parsed[1]=filset,  line_parsed[2]=dir,  line_parsed[3]=/tmp/test/my_test  ....

Comment: What is the `...`? The pattern is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enclosing the special characters in a "character class" (`[...]`) and moving the repetition character (`+`) outside:

```ruby
parts = line.split(/[<=>"\s]+/)
# => ["", "fileset", "dir", "/tmp/test/my_test", "includes", "all", "/"]

parts[1] # => "fileset"
parts[2] # => "dir"
parts[3] # => "/tmp/test/my_test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the right tool for parsing XML. You can use any XML parser you like, here I am using Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(line)
fileset = doc.css('fileset').first

fileset.attr 'dir'
#=> "/tmp/test/my_test"

fileset.attr 'includes'
#=> "all"
```

If you have another loop à la `each_line` around the code you showed us, chances are you can drop this altogether and parse the whole document in one run.